# After Debugging program is not running and displayed error messages

Tags: vb.net, sap-dotnet-connector

I am using VB.NET 2003 with SAP.NET Connector 2.0 for connecting SAP to .NET, but I am facing problem when I am debugging the program .

It just displayed the debug message after debugging and program is not running.

The Debug message is:

> 'DefaultDomain': Loaded 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\SAMNA\My Documents\Visual Studio Projects\SAP TO SAMNA\BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION\bin\BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe', Symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system\1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.xml\1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.xml.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.data\1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.data.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\sap.connector\2.0.0.0__50436dca5c7f7d23\sap.connector.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.web.services\1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\system.web.services.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\microsoft.visualbasic\7.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\microsoft.visualbasic.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.enterpriseservices\1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\system.enterpriseservices.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.enterpriseservices\1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\system.enterpriseservices.thunk.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.windows.forms\1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.windows.forms.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.drawing\1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\system.drawing.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\system.web\1.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\system.web.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'fz8uqxll', No symbols loaded.
>   'BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe': Loaded 'c:\windows\assembly\gac\sap.connector.rfc\2.0.0.0__50436dca5c7f7d23\sap.connector.rfc.dll', No symbols loaded.
>   The program '[5000] BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Please help me.

Comment: shoudn't you have used BAPI_TEXT_DESCRIPTION, and not BAPI_TEXT_DESCIPTION ?